# Why am I always logged in even after closing browser with remember me set to false

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, remember-me

I've creating a working user/login system with the laravel 4 framework and all is working well.

However I'm always logged into the site unless I run the logout process.
I would assume that if I login, close all browser windows and open the browser again I would be logged out. This is not the case.

In my Auth::attempt I am setting the $remember parameter to false even though it is false by default.

I have no idea why this is happening. If I logout, close all my  browser windows then open them again I am NOT logged in. So this works fine. But if I'm logged in, close all my browsers then open the browser again I am already logged in. Even thought I have specified remember to be false.

What is keeping me logged in? Why does it always remember my login? I cannot find any information on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

`'expire_on_close' => false,`

to

`'expire_on_close' => true,`

in `/app/config/session.php`.

Laravel isn't actually remembering you (you're not being authenticated again by your `remember_token`), problem is that you session cookie persists on browser close (since it hasn't expired) and Laravel sees you as a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I believe some browsers do this for you, not sure. Did you clear your browsing data / cookies after setting $remember to false and testing?

Comment: This is not normally an issues. I have tried in on multiple browsers. My browsers are not set up for any kind of auto login and I cannot control how other users use their browsers. Clearing the cache did not help. Same issue.

Comment: Hmmmmm, are you working within a framework that does things in the background? Or just plain php?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction! I'll have to look around aswell since I'm not familiar with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

What version you're on?

If below 4.1.26 than your answer is:

```
 http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26
```

Hope it will help!!! :G