# How to disable remeber_token when user close the browse in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token

When I use laravel 5 `Auth`

```
if (Auth::attempt($auth,true)) {
        // Check pass...
}
```

to login ,database will keep the **remeber_token** untill I do 
`Auth::logout()` ,

1.how to clean the remeber_token when I close the browse? 

2.how to set the remeber_token alive time?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183992/why-am-i-always-logged-in-even-after-closing-browser-with-remember-me-set-to-fal

Answer (score 3):

> martinstoeckli said:

It would be nice, if the Auth facade would offer a property to enable/disable the remember token. If a website does not intend to use this feature, it should not be necessary to to all the stuff anyway. I found a relatively easy circumvention of the remember functionallity and could not see any security problems, as long as you do not offer to set the remember token in your app:

```
class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
 ...
 public function getRememberToken()
 {
   return null; // not supported
 }

 public function setRememberToken($value)
 {
   // not supported
 }

 public function getRememberTokenName()
 {
   return null; // not supported
 }

 /**
  * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
  */
 public function setAttribute($key, $value)
 {
   $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
   if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
   {
     parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
   }
 }
 ...
```

You can refer this link http://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-how-to-disable-remember-token

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything when browser closing, because for doing something, some PHP script must be executed. Other words you can't *doing* anything till you call some url on your website.

Did you try set `expire_on_close` to true in `config/session.php`?

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Comment: I tried this before ,but not works! It still keeping, when I close the browse

Comment: still keeps token in session? It can not be.

Comment: keeping in the database remeber_token

Comment: yes it will, and you can't do anything with it when you are closing browser